# (Beginner) I am trying to create a customizable WizzBuzz game and I am getting these errors

Tags: c++

This is my very first project and I do not understand the error I am getting

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Multiple1 = 0;
    int Multiple2 = 0;
    cout << "Input your first Multiple: " << endl;
    getline(cin, Multiple1);
    cout <<"Your First Multiple is: " << Multiple1 << endl;

    cout << "Input your second Multiple: " << endl;
    getline(cin, Multiple2);

    cout << "Your Second Multiple is: " << Multiple2 << endl;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        if (i % Multiple1 == 0 && i % Multiple2 == 0)
            cout << "FizzBuzz" << endl;
        else
            if (i % Multiple1 == 0)
                cout << "Fizz" << endl;
            else
                if (i % Multiple2 == 0)
                    cout << "Buzz" << endl;
                else cout << i << endl;
    }    

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the errors:

[image]

[image]

Why does `getline(cin, Multiple1);` and `getline(cin, Multiple2);` not work when I run the code?

Error codes

```
E0304:  E0304   no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list

E0304: no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list

C2672: 'getline': no matching overloaded function found

C2784:'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'int'   


C2780: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)': expects 3 arguments - 2 provided


C2784: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'int'  

C2780: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)': expects 3 arguments - 2 provided

C2784: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'int'  

C2780: Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2780   'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)': expects 3 arguments - 2 provided
```

Comment: Avoid putting pictures. Post the errors in code format please.

Comment: [Documentation on `std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Pay special attention to the types of parameters it will accept. Easier to read version: `istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim);`

Comment: You also missed a ; on line 14

Comment: **Try something simpler first.** Write a program that takes a single number from the user and prints it. And consider stream input (`cin >> Multiple1;`) rather than `getline`.

Comment: @DP I have provided the error codes.

Comment: Please use a code beautifier. Write your code with whatever indentation and spacing, or lack thereof, that you want, but don't make other people read it in that way...

Comment: @Beta I believe I have already done the hard part with the programming of the FizzBuzz its just editing the variables I think.

Comment: @SpencerD I'm sorry this is very first time at coding.

Comment: There are important coding techniques that for some reason are never taught in programming courses. One is to implement new functionality in isolation as much as possible, and get it working perfectly before connecting it to other code. If you neglect that step and then get a bug, work backward: separate the functions and remove the ones that work, until you have the bug isolated. In this case the problem in in accepting input from the user, so concentrate on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in this instance, you are using the `std::getline()` function **incorrectly**. The purpose of `std::getline()` is to capture data from a standard input and then assign this data to a variable of **string type**.

In your code you are parsing `getline()` a variable of integer or **int type** to the function, and the compiler producing errors because of this.

There are two fixes to your code that can be made. One is the optimal way of fixing your code, and the other is if you absolutely must use `getline()` for some reason.

To fix your code without the use of `getline()`, I suggest you use the `>>` operator directly from your standard input to your variable like so;

```
int main()
{
    int Multiple1 = 0;
    int Multiple2 = 0;
    //First Multiple is taken in
    cout << "Input your first Multiple: " << endl;
    cin >> Multiple1;
    cout <<"Your First Multiple is: " << Multiple1 << endl;

    //Second Multiple is taken in
    cout << "Input your second Multiple: " << endl;
    cin >> Multiple2;
    cout << "Your Second Multiple is: " << Multiple2 << endl;
```

Alternatively if you absolutely must use `getline()`, you can cast from a string to an integer, whenever the string needs to be used in math or integer related functions, although this is bad practice in this scenario. Note I've changed Multiple1 & Multiple2 to string variables, and used the `stoi()` function which changes string to integer values, whenever the strings are used for comparisons against integers. This solution on works in c++11 or later.

```
int main()
{
    string Multiple1;
    string Multiple2;
    //First Multiple is taken in
    cout << "Input your first Multiple: " << endl;
    getline(cin,Multiple1);
    cout <<"Your First Multiple is: " << Multiple1 << endl;

    //Second Multiple is taken in
    cout << "Input your second Multiple: " << endl;
    getline(cin,Multiple2);
    cout << "Your Second Multiple is: " << Multiple2 << endl;


    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        if (i % stoi(Multiple1) == 0 && i % stoi(Multiple2) == 0){
            cout << "FizzBuzz" << endl;
        }
        else{
            if (i % stoi(Multiple1)  == 0){
                cout << "Fizz" << endl;
            }
            else{
                if (i % stoi(Multiple2)  == 0){
                    cout << "Buzz" << endl;
                }
                else{
                    cout << i << endl;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully all this clarifies your issue. By the way, using a native bash based compiler such as g++ may make your learning experience a little easier, as the errors can be easier to understand and google.

Answer (score 0):

As someone in the comments already pointed out, `getline` has specific parameters it can take. The second parameter must be of type `string`, but you are trying to pass in an `int`. This is why you are getting errors because the compiler is expecting the parameters to be of specific types.

Depending on what you want to do, there are many ways to get input from the user. Looking at the code you provided, it seems you simply want to get an `int` from the user. In this case, `getline` seems inappropriate because it will take in characters from the input stream and place them into a `string`. `cin` on its own would suffice:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense. What would I use instead of getline for an integer?